# How can I find all the differences between values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'A':3,'B',8,'C',12}
```

How could I loop through the dictionary such I that find the difference between each value and save the results.

For example, I want to (without hardcoding it) return a dictionary like the following using the dictionary above:

```
differences = {'A_minus_B':-5,'B_minus_A':5,
               'A_minus_C':-8,'C_minus_A':8,
               'C_minus_B':4,'B_minus_C':-4}
```

I can hardcode it but I would like my function to be more dynamic so that I can add more elements without having to write tedious lines of code to incorporate a new element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workable yet ugly loop solution:

```
differences = dict()
for k1,v1 in dictionary.items():
    for k2,v2 in dictionary.items():
        if k1==k2: continue
        differences[k1 + '_minus_' + k2] = v1-v2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) to generate pairs of distinct dictionary items and a dictionary comprehension to build a dictionary of differences.

```
from itertools import permutations

diff = {f'{ak} - {bk}': av - bv
        for (ak, av), (bk, bv) in permutations(dictionary.items(), 2)}

print(diff)
```

Outputs

```
{'A - B': -5, 'A - C': -9, 'B - A': 5, 'B - C': -4, 'C - A': 9, 'C - B': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about some dict comprehension ? No need for imports and its *relatively* readable.

```
{f'{k1}_minus_{k2}': d[k1] - d[k2] for k1 in d for k2 in d if k1 != k2}
```

(Replace the f-string with another form of concatenation if you're not in 3.6)

Output

```
{'A_minus_B': -5,
 'A_minus_C': -9,
 'B_minus_A': 5,
 'B_minus_C': -4,
 'C_minus_A': 9,
 'C_minus_B': 4}
```